How can I solve this large system of linear equations?
I have a large system of linear equations of the form:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\alpha_{11} c_1 + \ldots + \alpha_{1n} c_n &= 0\,, \\
\alpha_{21} c_1 + \ldots + \alpha_{2n} c_n &= 0\,, \\
\ldots\,,
\end{split} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$
which I would like to solve for the variables $c_k$.
I have 1343 unknowns and 23837 equations.
There a big redundancy in the equations, and I expect to be able to fix about 1000 unknowns only.
Do you have suggestions on how to attack this problem?
I am happy with numerical solutions, but when I use NSolve I struggle to make sure that it solved the linear system for the right number of variables.
To be more precise, in previous attempts, I would obtain different number of solved variables depending on how I would organize the system.
My interpretation was that a numerical error might make it unclear to Mathematica which equations are linearly dependent or not.
When I use Solve, the result seems trustworthy, but I was never able to apply Solve on the whole set of equations.
I was able to solve the first 6000 equations (which fixed about 300 unknowns).
What I have tried:
The equations can be downloaded here.
I am running the piece of code below to solve for the unknowns (gathered here in the variable Vars), where lmin and lmax serve as controllers for which equations to solve.
Ideally I would like to be able to set lmin=1 and lmax=23837.
The code also measures the timing.
For lmin=1 and lmax=1000, Solve takes less than 5 seconds on my laptop and solves for 61 unknowns.
At lmax=7000, my computer simply crashes.
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
<< Equations.mx

lmin = 1;
lmax = 1000;
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
AllEqs[[lmin ;; lmax]];
Solve[%, Vars][[1]];
% // Length
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - t1];
Clear[lmin, lmax]

Progress:
I have improved the system a little bit, by using RowReduce on reduced sets of equations and packing them back together.
I now have only 1276 equations! I can solve numerically using:
NewerEqs;
NumSols = NSolve[%, Vars][[1]];
Length[NumSols]

where I have updated the file above to define NewerEqs. This solves the system for 1019 unknowns. I would prefer an analytical solution, but I could not make the matrix smaller so far. Note that the file above also contains NumSols, as well as the matrix form of the equations under the name NewerMat.
But I am still unsure whether I can trust this result! Any idea on how to make sure that there is not some numerical pothole?

I should say that the file above also contains the solutions for lmax=6000 under the names Sols[1] and Sols[2].

I'll suggest extracting matrix and rhs using CoefficientArrays, then use LinearSolve or maybe LeastSquares.

@DanielLichtblau Thanks for your answer. I struggle to reduce the matrix to a square matrix. Do you have suggestions? Even MatrixRank does not run.

(i) Are the entries exact values? If so, maybe using N[...] on the matrix will make things faster. (ii) One might construct an upper triangular sparse 23837x1343 matrix, with 1s on the main diagonal and zeros below, and use it as a multiplier on the right of the input matrix. Now you have a square system.

My apologies. I updated the link. @bbgodfrey I am using Mathematica 13.3 and the code above seems to work fine to load the file, not sure why it would not work in 14.1..

@DanielLichtblau If I put a N, the matrix rank can indeed be computed in 90 seconds and gives 974. But can I trust this result? If I do a RowReduce on the numerical matrix, I see a lot of $10^{-22}$. If I use, e.g., N[...,10] to try increasing the precision, the matrix rank seems not to compute anymore. (I should say that if I take a low number of rows of the matrix and compare MatrixRank with and without N, it gives the same result)

And indeed, if I do RowReduce and then MatrixRank on the numerical matrix, I do not get the same number as MatrixRank on the original matrix.

Does RowReduce or LinearSolve work if you use N[…,100] on the input? I recommend trying this because, from your comments, I suspect machine precision is insufficient to handle the numeric conditioning of the problem.

@DanielLichtblau If I use NSolve[...,Vars,50] on the progress added to the post, I still find 1019 unknowns being fixed. Is that good enough to say that the numerical result is stable?

If you retry at 100 digits and get essentially the same result, I would think that shows stability.

@DanielLichtblau Yes, same result! Thanks a lot!

One last question: my variables are all named ct4[...], except for one which is called S. When I put NSolve[...,Vars], it calculates results for some ct4[...] and for S. I would like NSolve not to solve for S. I defined a new vector NewVars which contains all the variables except for S. But now NSolve[...,NewVars] gives me an Overflow occurred in computation warning. Any idea how I could circumvent this problem? Thanks again!

(I guess I can just invert the relation...)
